# JIRA gadget directory

Tags: jira, customization, jira-plugin

How can I create a new Gadget directory in JIRA for my custom gadgets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have custom gadgets in a JIRA plugin you don't need a new directory.

~Matt

Comment: Yes I do, now there are directories called: chart JIRA, others.., I need a directory called CompanyXY to store those gadget I make. With directory I mean in the screen where you choose the gadget to put on dashboard

Comment: Are you referring to the gadget category you can choose from when you add a gadget? The ones specified in the XML with <Optional feature="gadget-directory">
            <Param name="categories">
                JIRA
                Charts
            </Param>
        </Optional>

Comment: Yes I do already somenthing like: <Optional feature="gadget-directory"><Param name="categories>MY DIRECTORY</Param></Optional> BUT I don't have MY DIRECTORY, I don't know how to create it, the gadget goes in OTHER directory... I think I have to change JIRA CONFIG FILE somewhere.